# How do I automate Twitter Cards?

Tags: html, twitter

I am looking to implement Twitter Cards on a site that runs on Wordpress (documentation on Twitter Cards here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/cards)

Twitter asks for the following:

- meta name="twitter:card" value="summary"
- meta name="twitter:site" value="@nytimes"
- meta name="twitter:url" value="http://www.nytimes.com/2012/02/19/arts/music/amid-police-    presence-fans-congregate-for-whitney-houstons-funeral-in-newark.html"
- meta name="twitter:title" value="Parade of Fans for Houston’s Funeral"
- meta name="twitter:description" value="NEWARK - The guest list and parade of limousines with celebrities emerging from them seemed more suited to a red carpet event in Hollywood or New York than than a gritty stretch of Sussex Avenue near the former site of the James M. Baxter Terrace public housing project here."

My question is about three of the above (url, title and description) - if I add this code to the HEAD section of the site, is there anything I can put in to avoid hard-coding urls, titles and descriptions, and to instead pull it automatically from each page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can add some code to the header.php of your website that will extract the current URL, title and excerpt for description. I have recently created a post, that goes into setting Twitter Cards up as "automatic" for your site's home page, blog posts, pages and categories.

You use a combination of:

```
<?php if (is_single() || is_page() ) : if (have_posts() ) : while (have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

followed by:

```
<meta name="twitter:description" content="<?php echo get_the_excerpt();?>" />
<meta name="twitter:url" content="<?php the_permalink();?>" />
<meta name="twitter:title" content="<?php the_title();?>" />
```

For more details and pictures see my blog post http://www.davidtiong.com/how-to-add-twitter-cards-code-to-your-wordpress-website/

Comment: that if if while if statement is terrifyingly unreadable.. I'm pretty sure that ternary statements aren't intended to be nested, as they defeat the purpose of easy reading..

Answer (score 1):

With php: 
`<meta name="twitter:title" value="<?php echo $title ?>" >`
where `$title` is the title of your blog post.

Here is a discussion about Twitter cards WP plugin: https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/8548