# Twitter card not pulling in title

Tags: twitter, metadata, meta

The meta tags i'm using are not pulling in the title for each article I tweet, they only pull in the info in the meta tags below. How do I ensure it automatically displays each title?

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary">
<meta name="twitter:url" content="http://rucktales.com/">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@rucktales">
<meta property="og:title" content="Rucktales">
<meta property="og:description" content="Tales, opinion and comments from the World of Rugby Union">
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If asking how to dynamically set the tags for different articles, you're going to need to use a server-side technology (Node.js, PHP, Java, etc). Those will allow you to dynamically manipulate markup in the view based on the variables you provide to it.

Related answer showing an example in PHP: [How do I automate Twitter Cards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11061724/how-do-i-automate-twitter-cards?rq=1)

If looking only for a "linter" to verify whether you have it set up properly - Twitter provides one here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/cards/validation/validator